# Posting with Angular to Mongo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

My setup is NodeJS, MongoDB, and Angular. I'm currently trying to add POSTing capability to my test code but can't quite wrap my head around it. Currently I can pull data from the DB and I threw together a quick and dirty form/factory based on a number of examples I've seen to try to get the POST function working.

The problem I'm running into is actually getting the values to be added to the DB. When I submit the form, a new ObjectID is created in the DB with a "_v" field and a value of 0. So I know the POST is at least being sent to the DB, but the values I want are not. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid and any help is greatly appreciated.

**Here is my controller/factory setup:** (I named the POST factory "taco" so it would stand out. Also because they're delicious.)

```
      angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
     .factory('Users', ['$http', function($http) {
        return $http.get('/users');
     }])
    .factory('taco', ['$http', function($http) {
        return $http.post('/users');
     }])
     .controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'Users', function($scope, Users) {
        Users.success(function(data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        }).error(function(data, error) {
            console.log(error);
            $scope.users = [];
        });
     }])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', 'taco', function($scope, taco) {
     $scope.submit = function() {
      if ($scope.users.name) {
      $scope.name.post(this.name);
      $scope.name = '';
    }
  };
}]);
```

**Here is my form:**

```
<div>
   <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
      Enter the things:<br/>
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="user.name" placeholder="name" /><br/>
      <input type="text" ng-model="emp_id" name="user.emp_id" placeholder="EID" /><br/>
      <input type="text" ng-model="loc" name="user.loc" placeholder="location" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You have defined a service taco, injected it in your controller, but not used it. Also, your service returns a promise - your service does not POST anything. Did you go through the AngularJS tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post using the `$http` service you can do:

```
angular.module('myApp')

.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.post('/destination', {my: 'data'});
});
```

You're not sending any data in your `POST` request. The `taco` service just executes a `$http.post` call and returns the promise.

Please look at the `$http` service documents: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

I would define a function submit that would send the data once a user clicks on submit:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  $http.post('/destination', {my: 'data'});
}
```